# Wget redownload from start an unfinished file download and continue to download remaining files

Tags: linux, bash, download, wget

So I have this Bash subroutine to download files using wget and my problem now is how to re-download from start the unfinished file. The script downloads a lot of files and once the download fails, it will re-download all files and skip those successful downloads ("--continue" parameter). Is it possible to download from start the unfinished one (since it may be corrupted) then download the remaining files?

```
DownloadFile() {
  paramURL=$1
  paramFilename=$2

  if [ $flag_archive_fetch = "false"  ];
  then
      wget "--continue" "--timeout=180" "--tries=5" "$paramURL" "-O" "${scratch_dir}$paramFilename"
  else
      unzip -o "$archive_file" "$paramFilename" -d "${scratch_dir}"
  fi

  touch "${scratch_dir}$paramFilename"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the -nc (no clobber) flag to the wget command.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar script I am developing I test to see if the file is present. If it is I then compare the local md5 checksum to the one on the server. If the check fails I re-download the file.